# Переменные из другого файла. Bash

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Всем привет. Не получается использовать переменые из другого файла.

Ubuntu 16.04

есть файлы:

config_file:

```
#!/bin/bash
directory="test"
```

echo.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /ftp/test/config_file
echo $directory
```

Запускаю - sh echo.sh - ошибка source: not found

Подскажите в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для `/bin/sh` вместо команды `source` используется точка:

```sh
. /ftp/test/config_file
echo "$directory"
```

См. стандарт *POSIX*: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot.

Answer (score 4):

В интерпретаторе **sh** (/bin/sh) нет команды **source**. Вам надо запускать скрипт как `bash echo.sh` или ещё лучше просто `./echo.sh`, т.к. вы уже установили `/bin/bash` в качестве интерпретатора в первой строке.

P.S. Чтобы "просто выполнить файл" без явного указания **bash** как интерпретатора (т.е. просто `./echo.sh`), файл должен быть исполняемым.
Чтобы сделать его таковым достаточно один раз выполнить `chmod +x echo.sh`.

Comment: дополните, что нужно сделать `chmod +x echo.sh`, иначе только `bash ...` будет работать, у ТС мне кажется есть с этим проблемы

Comment: Есть, но она непереносима.